How to control within fixed effects in analysis of variance?
I will refer to common jargon in R to simplify communication, and I expect a solution in R, tidy or not.
I have a tibble with numeric column value, and character columns fe and treatment. There are 3 treatment and 3 classes of fixed effects.
Each combination of fe and treatment recur more than once.
I am interested in testing if treatment does not alter the location of value, nor its variance.
I want a frequentist test powered against the hypothesis that treatment alters location or variance. In other terms, my desired outcome is to be allowed to assume that treatment is ininfluent on the distribution of value, uniformely across fe.
In absence of fe, I would adopt a regular ANOVA test for the location, and a Levene test for the variance; even if I am confused about how should I determine my alphas.
If fe worked as a pairing variable, I would run paired tests.
But in this case there are more than 2 cases of values within the same fe.
Can you suggest me how to approach this test?
In theory I could run multiple tests, one for each fe; but I feel this method redundant and problematic in determination of alpha.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by alpha - it's conventionally used in frequentist statistics as the "significance threshold", i.e. the p-value that would cause you to reject the null. Alpha is set a priori (0.05 is a common value for alpha), so I'm not sure what you mean that you're confused about how to set it.
Otherwise, I think you're just asking for a test of equal variance among different groups, with two grouping variables treatment andfe. You can use bartlett's test like so:
bartlett.test(value ~ interaction(fe, treatment), data = df)


Knowing a priori multiple tests will occur, alpha is typically adjusted; sometimes omitted.
